# Preloader doesn't fade out after page is loaded

Tags: wordpress, preloader

I added a preloader and it doesn't fade out after loading the page!
My website is running on wordpress.
i don't know what's the prob;lem
thank you for your help

HTML:

```
<div class="loader-wrapper">   
        <div class="loader">
          <div class="loader__bar"></div>
          <div class="loader__bar"></div>
          <div class="loader__bar"></div>
          <div class="loader__bar"></div>
          <div class="loader__bar"></div>
          <div class="loader__ball"></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.loader-wrapper {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgb(240, 245, 245);
z-index: 999999;
}

.loader {
   position: absolute;
   top: 48%;
   left: 48%;
   width: 75px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//Preloader
preloaderFadeOutTime = 500;
function hidePreloader() {
var preloader = $('.loader-wrapper');
preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
}
hidePreloader();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think this can help you.

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
  document.getElementByClassName("loader-wrapper").style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```